# Cinematic/trailer heavy rhythm guitar sound

Tags: electric-guitar

[This track](https://soundcloud.com/liquidcinema/fight-or-flight), is following a very simple pattern yet sounds powerful and not overwhelming (well, considering that this is an aggressive track and guitar is used in half of it).

I've been trying to replicate the guitar sound for a while(as part of learning more about guitars) but all my attempts are not anywhere close. My assumption is that this is a set of slightly muted power chords played with very short attack/heavy impact and processed through screamer/compressor (please excuse my rudimentary knowledge) with some heavy EQing to make the sound more "round"(high end is suppressed a bit?).

Unfortunately trying both real guitar and VST(Schreddage2) processed through Guitar Rig(using both presets and trying to build everything from scratch) I am not able to get anywhere close.

So my ideas so far are:

- This is a reasonably simple sound to achieve but my lack of knowledge stops me from hearing the guitar separately from the final mix.
- Some of my assumptions about the way this is played/processed are wrong.

Considering that this is probably both, can someone please give me a pointer on what makes the guitar in this track sound the way it is?

Comment: This question might be off topic. That aside, it's not a typical guitar sound. I actually thought it was a synth until I heard fret noise. I wouldn't even bother with guitar rig - there's probably no real guitar amp or even guitar amp simulator in this sound. More likely it was processed using synth-like elements such as a ladder filter with filter overdrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Harmonizer type tool is in there, definitely. With multiple tracks, and a fair amount of filter use.

The distortion is reasonably easy to recreate though - I think I can identify 3 kinds in there: a fuzz and a 'metal' or very square wave distortion on a couple of layers, and overdrive on top of that.

As Michael suggested, for 'Epic' stuff, multiple layers using different EQ, distortion and reverb is a good way to go - then you can tweak the settings on each one.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be using a large amount of compressed gain and maybe even more than one guitar to achieve the full sound. I think there may also be a Whammy or some other pitch shifting device (e.g. Pitchfork or Boss Harmonist, ...) in play. There seems to be an 'ascending attack' which leads up to the chord, something you can obtain by pitch shifting (upwards). It just looks like it has several layers so:

Try stacking up layers of differently equalised guitars for a very full sound and maybe also add a bass. Then use a pitch shifting device for the lead guitar with most presence to shift up to the chord.